# Best way to split up an array in java to smaller arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

What is the best way to split up an array in a java method to smaller arrays? I want to be able to throw in any size array into `takeReceipts(String[])`

```
//Can handle any size array  
public void takeReceipts(String[] receipts){
//split array into smaller arrays, and then call handleReceipts(String[]) for every smaller array
}

//This method can only handle arrays with the size of 5 or less
private void handleReceipts(String[] receipts){
myNetworkRequest(receipts);
}
```

EDIT:

So it seems like copying the array into another array isn't efficient. Would something like this work?

```
    public void takeReceipts(String[] receipts){

    int limit = 5;
    int numOfSmallerArrays = (receipts.length/limit)+(receipts.length%limit);
    int from = 0;
    int to = 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfSmallerArrays; i++){
            List<String> subList = Arrays.asList(receipts).subList(from, to);
            from =+ limit;
            to =+ limit;
    }

}
```

Comment: Check out my answer. it handles it.

Comment: Your computation of `numOfSmallerArrays` is off - it should be `int numOfSmallerArrays = ((receipts.length+limit-1)/limit);` You also need to add a check `if (to >= receipts.length) to = receipts.length()-1;`

Comment: My solution handles that with  Math.min(i+5, receipts.length-1)

Comment: First, @dasblinkenlight why is `int numOfSmallerArrays = ((receipts.length+limit-1)/limit);` better than `int numOfSmallerArrays = (receipts.length/limit)+(receipts.length%limit);`?

Comment: Second, @dasblinkenlight where do I want to add that if statement?

Comment: @EGHDK Your expression does not compute the number of smaller arrays correctly: for example, if `receipts.length` is `199`, and `limit` is `10`, your expression would produce `28` instead of `20`, which is the correct result. The `if` needs to be inserted at the end of the loop to avoid the value of `to` from going over the limit.

Comment: Aha. I appreciate the example. And thank you for the if statement placement. I thought this would be a much simpler issue, thanks for your help!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Something is still not right. My if I pass in an array of I get two arrays. One with 4 and the second is empty. Ideas?

Comment: @EGHDK You wrote a `=+` instead of `+=` in your `for` loop. Here is a [running demo](http://ideone.com/15D1JZ).

Comment: Did you tried my solution? I am curious. did it work?

Comment: @hasan83 Yes. It was getting an off by one error somewhere. Array of 8 people return two arrays. One with 5 and another with 2.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Arrays.copyOfRange()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-T:A-int-int-):

```
int from = 0;
int to = 4;
String[] subArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(receipts, from, to)
```

Comment: Isn't [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy) faster?

Comment: `Arrays.copyOfRange()` uses `System.arraycopy()` internally.

Comment: I'm doing: `Arrays.copyOfRange(receipts, from, to)` from = 0 and to = 2, but the array I get back is only receipts[0] and receipts[1]. Why?

Comment: @EGHDK did you read the docs he linked? "to - the final index of the range to be copied, exclusive. (This index may lie outside the array.)"

Comment: So from is inclusive and to is exclusive?

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to using `List<String>` in place of `String[]` arrays, you could do partitioning in a very economical way:

```
List<String> subList = Arrays.asList(receipts).subList(from, to);
```

This approach does not make a copy of your array, providing a read-only view into the original array of receipts.

```
static final int LIMIT = 10;

public static void process(List<String> small) {
    if (small.size() > LIMIT) {
        System.out.print("Array is too big: "+small.size());
        return;
    }
    for (String s : small) {
        System.out.print(s+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void processBig(String[] receipts) {
    int numChunks = ((receipts.length+LIMIT-1)/LIMIT);
    int from = 0;
    int to = LIMIT;
    List<String> bigList = Arrays.asList(receipts);
    for (int i = 0 ; i != numChunks ; i++) {
        List<String> subList = bigList.subList(from, to);
        process(subList);
        from += LIMIT;
        to += LIMIT;
        if (to >= receipts.length) {
            to = receipts.length;
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/15D1JZ)

The consequences of taking this approach are that the changes made to the original array elements become "visible" through the view, and that you cannot change the resultant `subList` in any way.

Comment: How would I implement this in the `takeReceipts(String[] receipts)` method? Check my update. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
public void takeReceipts(String[] receipts){
    for (int i=0; i< receipts.length; i+=5)
        handleReceipts(Arrays.copyOfRange(receipts, i, Math.min(i+4, receipts.length-1)));
}

private void handleReceipts(String[] receipts){ 
}
```

OR

```
public void takeReceipts(String[] receipts){
    for (int i=0; i< receipts.length; i+=5)
        handleReceipts(Arrays.asList(receipts).subList(i, Math.min(i+4, receipts.length-1)));
}

private void handleReceipts(List<String> receipts){
}
```